# Adverb placement in "Let's simply share"

Tags: adverbs, word-order, adverb-position

To me the expression

> Let's simply share

seems wrong.

I've always thought the adverb should come after the verb. Is that correct?

Answer (score 5):

"Let's simply share" and "Let's share simply" have different meanings.

'Let's simply share" has the same meaning as "Let's *just* share". That is, let's share without any more fuss, or making too much of sharing.

"Let's share simply" has the meaning of sharing *in a simple way*, that is, to avoid complication which could arise if we were to attempt sharing like "You can have 20% of the cake, and I'll take 35.47%, and the rest will go to Jake." That's bound to bring some sort of trouble.

They have different meanings because the adverb has changed positions. Adverbs *can go anywhere*. For example:

> Simply, let's share
>   Let's share simply.
>   Let's simply share.

Each of them means different things, and both of them are grammatically correct.

Comment: Good answer. Sorry to be a grammar Nazi by correcting your final sentence... though this is the appropriate place I suppose. :P

Comment: Though adverbs are versatile, they certainly can't 'go anywhere'. And they don't all behave identically: John shuffled the cards slowly. / John slowly shuffled the cards. // John kicked the ball hard. / *John hard kicked the ball. See 'A Minimalist Account of the Distribution of Adverbs' _ Rhanghyeyun Kim >> It's good to distinguish adverbial usage ('I would speak frankly with him') from pragmatic marker usage ('I would, frankly, speak with him).